# Linearity of variational derivative?

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Just wondering. Suppose we have a functional of the form

$$
E(y) = \int_X\mathcal{L}(x,y,y')dx
$$

The variational derivative is given by

$$
\frac{dE}{dy} = \frac{d\mathcal{L}}{dy} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{d\mathcal{L}}{dy'}
$$

Because the meaning of the variational derivative is *somehow* a gradient is there a way to define a linear mapping that maybe I'm not seeing?

I'm asking because usually these expressions are quite complicated and I really can't see any linearity at all.

Answer (score 0):

The variational derivative of the functional $E(y)$ is a functional of two functions,
$$
\mathcal{D}E(y)(\phi) = \left. \frac{d}{d\lambda} E(y+\lambda\phi) \right|_{\lambda=0}
$$

In general the functional $\phi \mapsto \mathcal{D}E(y)(\phi)$ is *not* linear, but for example when $E(y) = \int \mathcal{L}(x, y, y') \, dx$ then it is in fact linear.

#### Wikipedia articles:

- [Functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative)
- [Gâteaux derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative)
- [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative)

Comment: You should elaborate a bit more...